# Kubernetes ingress IP is set to docker0 ip

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I'm trying to use the kubernetes ingress resource on bare metal with no cloud provider.

I created an ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foobar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: echoheaders-x
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
```

however, when I view the ingress, I get this IP:

```
[root@kubemaster]# kubectl get ing
NAME      HOSTS       ADDRESS      PORTS     AGE
nginx     foobar.com   172.17.0.1   80        12m
```

That IP address seems to correspond with the docker0 IP address on all my kubelet nodes.

Is there a way to set this IP? All the tutorial's I've read seem to have this IP be routable.

Here's my nginx-controller yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  labels:
    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
        name: nginx-ingress-lb
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3
        name: nginx-ingress-lb
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        # use downward API
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
        # we expose 18080 to access nginx stats in url /nginx-status
        # this is optional
        - containerPort: 18080
          hostPort: 18080
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
        - --nginx-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-controller
```

Comment: IMO the IP address is set by the ingess controller. What ingress controller are you using?

Comment: nginx controller, have added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was the kubelet configuration. By default, the kubelet will listen on `0.0.0.0` and because `docker0` is the first available address, it grabbed `docker0`'s IP.

I added the following to the kubelet config:

```
--address=<actualip> --node-ip=<actualip>
```

And it registered correctly.